# Error when creating an anaconda environment in Anaconda prompt

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have been trying to create a simple environment in Anaconda, but I keep getting this error.

> (base) C:\Users\mwpan>conda create -n pythondata python=3.7 anaconda
> WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1216):
> KeyError('pkgs_dirs') Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
> 1082, in **call**
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
> 87, in _main
> exit_code = do_call(args, p)   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py",
> line 84, in do_call
> return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py",
> line 21, in execute
> if is_conda_environment(context.target_prefix):   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 591, in target_prefix
> return determine_target_prefix(self)   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 1738, in determine_target_prefix
> return locate_prefix_by_name(prefix_name)   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 1681, in locate_prefix_by_name
> envs_dirs = context.envs_dirs   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 517, in envs_dirs
> return mockable_context_envs_dirs(self.root_writable, self.root_prefix, self._envs_dirs)   File
> "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 91, in mockable_context_envs_dirs
> fixed_dirs += join(user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME), 'envs'),   File
> "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\appdirs.py",
> line 67, in user_data_dir
> path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)   File
> "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\appdirs.py",
> line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
> from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be
> found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
> 1214, in print_unexpected_error_report
> message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
> File
> "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py",
> line 237, in get_main_info_str
> info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key]) KeyError: 'pkgs_dirs'
>
> ## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
> ```
>
> 1082, in **call**
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
> 87, in _main
> exit_code = do_call(args, p)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py",
> line 84, in do_call
> return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py",
> line 21, in execute
> if is_conda_environment(context.target_prefix):
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 591, in target_prefix
> return determine_target_prefix(self)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 1738, in determine_target_prefix
> return locate_prefix_by_name(prefix_name)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 1681, in locate_prefix_by_name
> envs_dirs = context.envs_dirs
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 517, in envs_dirs
> return mockable_context_envs_dirs(self.root_writable, self.root_prefix, self._envs_dirs)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
> line 91, in mockable_context_envs_dirs
> fixed_dirs += join(user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME), 'envs'),
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\appdirs.py",
> line 67, in user_data_dir
> path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
> File "C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\appdirs.py",
> line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
> from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.
>
> `$ C:\Users\mwpan\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py create -n pythondata python=3.7 anaconda`
>
> environment variables: conda info could not be constructed.
> KeyError('pkgs_dirs')
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
>
> If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
> future releases of conda. Would you like conda to send this report to
> the core maintainers?

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?